# Turn background transparent when text field is empty and no cursor (onUnfocus)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

When text field is empty and no cursor int the text field want to transparent and spell checker is not working. the showing the result `<div>` want to little left.

That code CSS or JavaScript or in PHP.

```
<form method="post" name="tasktitleform">
  <input id="Search" class="search" type="text" name="Search" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" />
  <input class="save" value="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

The footer code is not sticking under the window. That's way I copied from google and simply change the color to light yellow.

In this spellcheck not working CSS not working in the IE.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not clear. Based on your question title, here is jquery snippet for changing opacity on focus and focusout events

```
    $("#tbx").focus(function(){
      $(this).css("opacity","1");
   });
   $("#tbx").focusout(function(){
     if($(this).val()=="")
    $(this).css("opacity","0.6");
  });
```

`jsfiddle sample` http://jsfiddle.net/zxdwa0e8/3/

Comment: I see your problem you are using IE. For cross browser compatibility you muse use follow css value for working with IE version 7, 8 and 9,
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity: 0.6;
Secondly don't use newer jquery. You can test whether jquery is working or not from dev console of IE. As far as I tested, jquery 1.8.3 is stable for IE. 
I host sample for your issues here without jsfiddle and tested with IE. [http://instant-test.appspot.com/1.html](http://instant-test.appspot.com/1.html)

Comment: OMG! you can set initial opacity to 100% if your textbox is surely auto focused.

Comment: to focus to input box on any key press, try to use $(document).keydown(function(){ $("#tbx").focus(); }); in document-ready scope. I updated solution, you can check it [http://instant-test.appspot.com/1.html](http://instant-test.appspot.com/1.html)

Comment: showing submit on focus can simply be achieved by adding ` $("input[type='submit']").show();` in focus event handler and ` $("input[type='submit']").hide();` in focusout event handler. if your text box is autofocused, remove `display:none;` from css of submit.

Comment: your question is not clear, please post as new question with more detail if this issue is not related to your previous problem even within one html page. you should not use comment area as live chat.